# creating special primary key in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am building my DB model using sequelize, and my tables are the following:

[image]

My issue is that, how could I make the primary key (id) of the packageTypes record as follows:
`productId + id`  ,
so if the productId is `1` and the packageType id is `3` so the id will be `13`

Comment: In short, don't. Create a composite primary key containing both `(productId, packageTypeID)`. Less duplication, same uniqueness effect.

Comment: thank you, so I'll keep the primary key as default

Comment: Be aware that Sequelize doesn't support composite PKs.

Comment: So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163675/composite-primary-key-in-sequelize) isn't right?